# How to get parameters from a "dependent" dialog

Tags: dialog, xul, xulrunner

In my XUL application, I open a dialog window, by this code:

```js
var win = myWindow.openDialog("chrome://mywindow/content/mydialog.xul",
                  "Dialog creation",
                  "chrome, dialog, modal, resizable=yes",
                           params).focus();
```

And I access the information passed by user, by this code:

```js
if (params.out){     
    dialogVariablesValues = params.out['inputValues'];
    sameDialog = params.out['sameDialog'];  
    (...)
}
```

When the OK button in the dialog window is clicked, the window is closed, the if (params.out) becomes true and I can get the values. I don't have any problem with this approach. The problem is that I need to change my dialog window to be dependent. So I have changed the code to:

```js
var win = myWindow.openDialog("chrome://mywindow/content/mydialog.xul",
                  "Dialog creation",
                  "chrome, dialog, dependent, resizable=yes",
                           params).focus();
```

But params.out is always null...

Does anyone know how I can get the values when the dependent dialog is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a dependent dialog the execution continues after the `openDialog()` call even though the dialog is still open. So you want your code to be "notified" when that dialog is closed. The easiest solution should be passing a callback in the params and changing the dialog to call your callback when it is closed. So the code opening the dialog would look like this:

```js
params.callback = function(inputValues, sameDialog)
{
  // Do something with the dialog result here
};
myWindow.openDialog(..., params).focus();
```

And the dialog would have code like this:

```js
var inputValues = ...;
var sameDialog = ...;
window.addEventListener("unload", function()
{
  // Dialog is being closed, call the callback
  window.arguments.callback(inputValues, sameDialog);
}, false)
```